# How to name the columns of my with rbind generated matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have several vectors that contain numbers and one with characters, which contains the names to the columns.
I created a matrix with the numbers vectors using the rbind function. 
Can anyone help me how I use the characters vector to name the columns? 
If i built a matrix from scratch with the matrix()-funktion i would have used colnames(), but since I had to use rbind, I dont know how to name it.

Comment: `colnames(the.name.of.your.matrix) <- c("column A", "column B"... "column x")` but without reproducible data and an example of your intended output it is impossible to provide a more in depth answer

Comment: The names are contained in a long vector. There are over 70 columns, so the vector has this many items. Do I need to put them in one by one? I tried colnames(matrixname) <- nameofvector  . This didnt work :(

Comment: If your name vector has the same length as colnames(matrix) your attempt should work.

Comment: Are you handling a matrix or a dataframe?? **Reproducible code as an example will help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vectors you have should be columns in the output dataframe, than you need to use cbind() function:

```
# first vector
v1 <- rnorm(1:10)

#second vector
v2<- 1:10

# third vector
v3 <- runif(10, min=-10, max=10)

# names for the columns:
cnames <- c("first", "second", "third")

# combine your vectors as columns
my.data<- cbind(v1, v2, v3)
colnames(my.data) <- cnames

# The above result is a matrix. You can convert it to data frame if necessary
my.data <- as.data.frame(my.data)
my.data
#         first second     third
# 1   0.1546350      1  1.441857
# 2   0.1954627      2 -2.557443
# 3   1.0097335      3  2.856407
# 4  -0.6707548      4  2.244222
# 5   0.6522662      5 -5.248731
# 6  -0.4794330      6 -1.406135
# 7  -1.3191673      7  6.687989
# 8   0.4762472      8  1.562045
# 9   0.7190201      9 -1.301451
# 10  0.3914469     10  2.100174
```

If the vectors you have are the rows in your future data frame, then:

```
# first vector
v1 <- rnorm(1:3)

#second vector
v2<- rnorm(1:3)

# third vector
v3 <- rnorm(1:3)

# forth vector
v4 <- rnorm(1:3)

# names for the columns:
cnames <- c("first", "second", "third")

# combine your vectors as columns
my.data<- rbind(v1, v2, v3, v4)
colnames(my.data) <- cnames

# The above result is a matrix. You can convert it to data frame if necessary
my.data <- as.data.frame(my.data)
my.data
#        first     second      third
#v1  0.2637774 -0.2010000  0.5637698
#v2 -0.1368421  0.2559511 -1.2920349
#v3 -0.8087293  0.4321634 -0.2470514
#v4  0.1954442 -1.6450399  0.4054812
```